# Using Macrium Reflect on other PCs

Tags: macrium

Can Macrium Reflect be used on all other PCs beside Mac computers?

Comment: Macrium Reflect is for Windows Only, no MAC version of that software. The MR boot CD may work on a MAC though, never tried it.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, disclaimer: I'm a developer for Macrium, so I have a slight (!) advantage answering this question.

The Reflect product itself can be installed on the operating systems described in [CGA's answer](https://superuser.com/a/270699/26996) both in 32 and 64-bit editions. However, recovery can be run from our rescue CDs on any system that supports MBR or UEFI booting - that is, most systems there are :) Windows systems can then be recovered from these images.

Whilst Reflect cannot be run on general purpose Linux systems, one of our Rescue CD formats is Linux-based, and we can image ext4 partitions from Windows (and therefore recover them from a recovery disk, or from Windows).

Contrary to the name of our company, Reflect does not run on Mac OS/OS X platforms at this time - Apple has already produced [Time Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Machine_%28Mac_OS%29) which can perform full system backups for Mac platforms.

Answer (score 0):

According to their site it works on the following operating systems:

XP, Vista, Windows 7, Server 2003 and Server 2008. 32 and native 64 Bit.